# how to share xml file using shareduserID android

Tags: android, xml

I am having two applications.I have having a xml file in one of those applications.How can i access the same xml file in other application using shareduserID??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean that your XML file is in the `files` folder of your app.

Assign the same sharedUserId in the manifest of both applications.

This will allow you to access private files of your other application. The one thing that is not documented and had me struggling for a while is that the sharedUserId MUST have dots in it (e.g. aaa.bbb or aaa.bbb.ccc or...)

Comment: In addition to the apps having the same sharedUserId, they both must be signed by the same certificate.